# ! Missing number, treated as zero error in latex when using for loop

Tags: algorithm, latex

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{AlgorithmCH election algorithm}
\label{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{CHElection}

\For{each node i }
\EndFor

\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

I have this code used to write an algorithm in LATEX but I received this error (`! Missing number, treated as zero error`) when I point to the error, I saw it at `\End` for. Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error please?

This are the packages I added for writing an algorithm

```
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}  
\usepackage[ruled,noresetcount,noend]{algorithm2e}
```

Comment: You cannot load [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) *and* [`algpseudocode`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). In your preamble, just load `\usepackage{algorithm} \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}`.

Comment: ...well, [you can](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131652/5764), but it's best not to mix them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't load [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) when you're using [`algpseudocode`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). The former creates an `algorithm` floating environment, but in order to use `algorithmic` from `algpseudocode`, you should load `algorithm` instead (from the [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{AlgorithmCH election algorithm}
  \label{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{CHElection}{}
      \For{each node~$i$}
      \EndFor
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Note also the second (mandatory) argument for `\Procedure`, which designates the arguments passed to the procedure. It can also be left blank, but you need to explicitly include this.

Answer (score 2):

I just removed that error by placing the packages in the folloing order

```
\usepackage{algopseudocode}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}  not required
\usepackage{algorithm}
```